# How to add to cart without reloading page on woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a website and I want to show the options of the products with variations on the main and shop page.

I use this code to acomplished that:

```
/**
 * Replace add to cart button in the loop.
 */
function iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/**
 * Use single add to cart button for variable products.
 */
function iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
    return;
    }

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}

/**
 * Customise variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Remove qty selector and simplify.
 */
function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And works great, but if you add a product to the cart, also sends you to the page of that product. So I add this code, so the page just reloads.

```
function iconic_add_to_cart_form_action( $redirect ) {
    if ( ! is_archive() ) {
        return $redirect;
    }

    return '';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', 'iconic_add_to_cart_form_action' );
```

Can someone help me? I want to add the product withou reloading or sending the clientes to another page.

Thanks!!

Comment: There would be a bit of work. You would need to handle the request with Ajax or similar so you don't refresh the page, but still send the information over.

Comment: Did you try to "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives"  option on product tab in woocommerce settings ?

Comment: @Ash0ur yes. The AJAX buttons work great on single products. I think it is the type of button I add with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button function to this as i added an ID for this add to cart button:

```
/**
 * Customise variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Remove qty selector and simplify.
 */
  function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button()
{
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button   type="submit" class="custom_add_to_cart single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html($product->single_add_to_cart_text()); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint($product->get_id()); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint($product->get_id()); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

**and here is the Ajax code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  $('.custom_add_to_cart').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next().next().attr('value');
    var data = {
      product_id: id,
      quantity: 1
    };
    $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
    $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {

      if (!response) {
        return;
      }
      if (response.error) {
        alert("Custom Massage ");
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');
        return;
      }
      if (response) {

        var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
        url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
        $.post(url, function (data, status) {
          $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
          if (data.fragments) {
            jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

              jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
            });
          }
          jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
        });
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');

      }

    });

 });
});
```

I Just tested with your code on my local host and it's working fine

Comment: Hi: thanks for the code.I try it on my web; but it only works with the first product of the list. If I try to add another product the page reloads.

Comment: @GregMinaya it's my fault i did mistake try it now :) and let me know if everything went well

Comment: thanks!! finally I find the problem: I tought you change the AJAX code, but It was the php code where you made change. I finally noticed that testing your working version. Now works great! thanks!!

Comment: @kashalo I just want to upload my cart page by ajax, And this code doesnt help me! do you guys know any solution? I stuck with it for about 2 weeks

Comment: @Nadia actually I didn't touch WC for a long time, but if you can describe to me what exactly you want exactly, i'll be happy to help, just PM or ask another question over here

Comment: @kashalo thanks for helping, actually I am ceating a plugin  which put product in shopping list(/cart) page to next shopping list, after user click on add to next shopping list, i will remove the product from cart page and I want to reload the cart page by ajax like what the remove button do,jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");  did noting! WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments() return error because WC_AJAX  is not define in my plugin! thanks in advance