# Show product variations on shop pages in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the same problem which was talked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828575/3730754)

I have added the code using PHP snippets plugin, but I'm not sure where to add the ajax code

I just want to add product variations on shop page with possiblity of adding to cart without reloading the page

you can also check my website over [here](https://hashtom.net)

Comment: Adding links to a website which will be fixed does not help future users.  Describe the problem and include the code that is not working.  And if the question has already been asked and resolved, then you should not be posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't have access to your main script files and you can't add another files then you can add the script to WordPress Footer using `wp_footer` hook as follow:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'myScript');

function myScript()
{
    ?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
"use strict";

$('.custom_add_to_cart').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next().next().next().attr('value');
    var data = {
    product_id: id,
    quantity: 1
    };
    $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
    $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {

    if (!response) {
        return;
    }
    if (response.error) {
        alert("Custom Massage ");
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');
        return;
    }
    if (response) {

        var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
        url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
        $.post(url, function (data, status) {
        $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
        if (data.fragments) {
            jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

            jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
            });
        }
        jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
        });
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');

    }

    });

});
});
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: everything works fine but there is just a little problem, currently, it adds the wrong version of a product to the cart, my products have different prices based on the weight that you choose, the code is always adding the price for the lowest weight available :-?

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHamidi no actually it's adding the product which the customer chose i just checked  am going to check it on your site

Comment: unfortunately, its how it's working on my site, still couldn't find a way to fix it

Comment: @kasholo I believe same would happen to your site too, because all the prices are the same on your site, you haven't noticed it yet

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHamidi i will check it

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHamidi just change this line in the script 
`var id = $(this).next().next().next().attr('value'); `

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHamidi i have modified the script above if u want just copy and past it and u should be fine

Comment: it's working absolutely nice, thanks a lot for your awesome codes

Comment: @kasholo is there a way to make the code to respond faster? if you try to add a few products fast, it would result in adding the product with less price and wrong weight,, thanks in advance

Comment: @MohammadMahdiHamidi if you inspect the code you will see it's change the value instantly so am not sure how much more faster u want

Answer (score 1):

add the whole code under here into your php snippet plugin and it would work like a charm
thanks to @kacholo

```js
/**
 * Replace add to cart button in the loop.
 */
function iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'iconic_change_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );

/**
 * Use single add to cart button for variable products.
 */
function iconic_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
    return;
    }

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );

    woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart();
}

/**
 * Customise variable add to cart button for loop.
 *
 * Remove qty selector and simplify.
 */
  function iconic_loop_variation_add_to_cart_button()
{
    global $product;

    ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
        <button   type="submit" class="custom_add_to_cart single_add_to_cart_button button"><?php echo esc_html($product->single_add_to_cart_text()); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint($product->get_id()); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint($product->get_id()); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
    </div>
    <?php
}
function iconic_add_to_cart_form_action( $redirect ) {
    if ( ! is_archive() ) {
        return $redirect;
    }

    return '';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', 'iconic_add_to_cart_form_action' );
add_action('wp_footer', 'myScript');

function myScript()
{
    ?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
"use strict";

$('.custom_add_to_cart').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).next().next().next().attr('value');
    var data = {
    product_id: id,
    quantity: 1
    };
    $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
    $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {

    if (!response) {
        return;
    }
    if (response.error) {
        alert("Custom Massage ");
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');
        return;
    }
    if (response) {

        var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
        url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
        $.post(url, function (data, status) {
        $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
        if (data.fragments) {
            jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

            jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
            });
        }
        jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
        });
        $('.custom_add_to_cart').parent().removeClass('loading');

    }

    });

});
});
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code. It shows the variations on the product page, but it does not successfully add the variations to the cart?